# Shadow DOM, aim of using it

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow-dom

I have studied Shadow DOM recently, and I was wondering what are the aims of using it instead of the main one.

What does it gives ? Why dont we use standard DOM instead of it (except for styling scoping) ?

Comment: read this:http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/  and http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It allows you to encapsulate functionality, effectively putting it in a black box. It means you can create [reusable] components whose inner workings aren't exposed; this is impossible using standard DOM.

As an example, take HTML input elements. So, say, the `file` type of input. To use it on an HTML page, you simply add `<input type="file" />`, and it works. You don't need to add any extra code or HTML or CSS to handle how it works, it just does, and you can't access the internal bits of it. If you were to write a piece of UI, using HTML/CSS/JS, that did the same thing, it would be fairly complex. But the `file` input is just a single tag that you can use anywhere, it always does the same thing. The web component family of specs allow you to create your own elements that work in this way, and the Shadow DOM is a critical part of this. You can create a new element, like `<my-fantastic-file-input />`, with its functionality encapsulated. It has its own internal DOM subtree, but that subtree isn't *directly* accessible; ditto with scoped styles. The new component does not expose its implementation details to the document.

You *can* do most of this stuff using the DOM, *but* the implementation will be wholly tied into the document/application structure. With components, you extract that implementation, and you can reuse it, pass it around, publish it and let other people drop it into their applications/documents, and be sure it will work in exactly the same way, anywhere. You cannot really do that as things currently stand by using the standard DOM.

This is from 2011, and slightly out-of-date, but it's a list of some possible use cases for the component model: http://www.w3.org/2008/webapps/wiki/Component_Model_Use_Cases